# What is JUnit's Expectations() Equivalent to in Cucumber?

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, bdd

I am new to Cucumber, and am trying to write some functional tests.  I want to know the Cucumber equivalency of JUnit's Expectations(). In Expectations(), you're able to expect an Exception (or just result) to be returned when some service method is called.  I want to know how to force an exception of a service in Cucumber?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cucumber JVM : Test if the correct exception is thrown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272161/cucumber-jvm-test-if-the-correct-exception-is-thrown)

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 so long story short, I need to test my restReponse which depends on whether an external service I'm calling is throwing a 400 or 500 response. But I don't see any way I can possibly throw an exception in that service that I'm trying to call..

Comment: Take a look at [Doug's response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752528/how-to-simulate-an-http-500-error-on-my-asp-net-app)